# How to convert Axes Coordinate Values to Data Coordinate Values in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have values for matplotlib in the Axes coordinate and I need to convert them to my axis's Data Coordinate values.

https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [linked tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) tells you how to do it.

```
ax.transAxes + ax.transData.inverted()
```